# I do not understand why Python give me a np.darray object is not callable

Tags: python, numpy

> **I want to find the nearest point to point p but it does not work**

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
point = np.array([[1,1],[1,2],[1,3],[2,1], [2,2],[2,3], [3,1], [3,2], [3,3]])
p = np.array([2.5,2])
plt.plot(point[:,0], point[:,1], "ro")
plt.plot(p[0], p[1], "bo")
```

> ```
> **This section is where it got the error**
> ```

```
distance = np.zeros(point.shape[0])
for i in range(len(distance)):
    distance[i] = distance(p, point[i])
distance[4]
```

Comment: distance(p, point[i]) I assume you have a function called distance ?. Either rename it or rename the distance array

Answer (score 0):

replace `distance(p, point[i])` with distance calculation

```
distance = np.zeros(point.shape[0])
for i in range(len(distance)):^M
    distance[i] = sum((p-point[i])**2)**0.5
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to rename the array `distance` to something else. Currently in the line `distance[i] = distance(p, point[i])` Python tries to call your array instead of the `distance()` function.